# xamarin (ios) httpclient get and post to router without internet connection

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I have one esp8266(arduino) project, at the first time, device start as a Access point, so the mobile can connect via wifi to setup my network name and password and save on the device, so the next time device can connect to the network.

So, everything is fine, i connect to access point and tested webserver and posts with mobile browser.

Now i want to migrate the post/get to xamarin forms app, but i cant post with xamarin on iphone.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.144.2/foo");
```

exception: "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

Obviously i dont have internet connection, just want post to access point via local address(192.168.x.x), how can i workaround.

Thanks

Edited:
VS 2019 16.8.3
Xamarin forms 5.0.0.1829-pre6
Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/> 
    </dict>
```

Comment: Hi, do you test in a android device? If so, you need to check whehter add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` inside `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: No, i dont have a android device, for now i am using webview instead, but i have to return to this issue, thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, not knowing which device platform(Android/iOS/UWP) to run it. You mean that run the project in a android simulator? If so, you also need to add this permission.

Comment: No i run in iphone physical device, because i have to connect via wifi to my arduino(access point), can i do this on android simulator?

Comment: Sorry, but i mentioned iphone, discreetly on third paragraph

Comment: Okey. If so, you can't use simulator to connect that unless your PC can connect that wifi.

Comment: I will give a try in android simulator, it can be related to apple info.plist

Comment: From the question, the browser of iPhone works?

Comment: Yes, everything works on iphone browser´s, and i cant connect with android simulator...